# Why sharing data across controllers doesn't work in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am trying to build a simple username login system. This is just to record username which I can use in my various controllers.

But, for some reason, I am unable to get `$scope.userName` value in `abcController`

The essence of this problem is sharing data across controllers.

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('userNameController',function ($scope, $log, Config, Session)
{
  Session.updateSession($scope.userName);
});

app.controller('abcController',function ($scope, $log, Config, Session)
{
    $scope.userName=Session.data.username;
     //some other code
});
```

**resource.js**

```
app.factory('Session', function() {
    var Session = {
        data: {},
        updateSession: function(userName) {
            Session.data = { "username": userName }
        }
    };
    return Session;
});
```

As soon as a user clicks on LogIn button a twitter-bootstrap modal(popup) will appear and ask user to enter their username.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="userNameController">
<button class="btn" id="enterUsernameBtn" href="#userNameModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" title="Enter Username">Login</button>
</div>

    <!-- UserName Modal -->
    <div id="userNameModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userNameModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="userNameModalLabel">Enter your username</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p><b>UserId</b></p>
            <div class="input-append">
                <input class="pull-left" id="userIdTextBox" type="text" style="left:8px; width:160px" ng-controller="userNameController" ng-model="userName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please feel free to suggest, if there is better way to do what I am trying to do above.

Comment: Isn't this because your abcController has already run by the time your userNameController sets the userName property? Presumably $scope.userName === undefined in abcController. What happens if you use Session.data.username directly when you need it? You might need to attach the Session resource to your abcController $scope.

Comment: you may find this article interesting http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/03/how-to-create-singleton-angularjs-services-in-4-different-ways/

Comment: @cirrus, you are right. That is what might be happening. I wrote `app.run(function(Session) {}); //bootstrap session;` in app.js which is referenced before any other .js files. That didn't help. Haven't I already attached the Session resource to abcController? Please help, angularJS noob here.

Comment: You could also use $rootScope but I think your resource approach is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it help if you define your resource like this?

```
app.factory('Session', function() {
     var Session = {
        data: { username: undefined }, // ensure object ref to attach to
        updateSession: function(userName) {
            Session.data.username = userName; // do NOT recreate the object above
        }
    };
    return Session;
});
```

I think what may be happening (and I can't see all of your code) but I don't think `username` is set when you take a reference in `abcController`. By defining a shared reference in your object schema first that abcController can attach to, it will reflect the changes later when updateSession() is called.

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cWkP2/1/) using your service idea.

Comment: I read somewhere, should writing `app.run(function(Session) {}); //bootstrap session;` in `app.js` will help?

Comment: btw, I defined my resource as you suggested, that didn't help.

Comment: To be sure, console.log() in both controllers so you can see the order, and set username to an initial dummy value, say "xxxx". When you change the value you should see it reflected in abcController, but remember you need a '.' reference. If you *change* the underlying reference you'll break the link between the two. In your previous code you had REASSIGNED data completely, so abcController was binding to a DIFFERENT data{} object, not to mention an undefined username property.

Comment: I put console.log() in both controllers. In abcController initially username value is undefined. But if I put `$scope.userName=Session.data.username;` under a temp function which I call late on a temp button click, I can see username value getting propagated from userNameController, now I have to figure out, how to  get current username so that in view I can do `{{username}}` from `abcController`. I tried putting `$scope.$watch('Session.data.username', function(){$scope.username=Session.data.username})` in abcController, that didn't work.

Comment: $watch() works on values in scope, so Session won't necessarily work. You shouldn't need it though as long as you have an event from an ng- handler, such as ng-click. AngularJS will check to see what's changed at the end of the click event. So as long as your $scope.username == Session.data.username and it's the same object your change will be reflected.

Comment: Actually, you've got userName bound to the model on your input tag, so your $digest cycle *should* be running. So I suspect the issue may still be object reference related.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. Though I couldn't get it to work this way, instead used emit and broadcast way to do it. But, you made useful comments and provided useful info.

Comment: @Watt Thanks, that's very kind. Actually, if you look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hBZj4/ your service idea is working, but *only* if you press the second button (to trigger the $digest). So I think if you combine that with the broadcast paradigm (rather then sending username in the messge) you'll have a good, more flexible model.

Comment: Got the service version working. http://jsfiddle.net/cWkP2/1/ Note the '.' in data.username

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution using `emit` and `broadcast`.
Full code example in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxafF/)

**app.js**

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    /*
     Receive emitted message and broadcast it.
     Event names must be distinct or browser will blow up!
     */
    $rootScope.$on('handleEmit', function(event, args) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast', args);
    });
});
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('userNameController',function ($scope, $log, Config)
{

  $scope.submitUserName= function ()
  {
      // Session.updateSession($scope.userName);
      $scope.$emit('handleEmit', {username: $scope.userName});
  };

});

app.controller('abcController',function ($scope, $log, Config)
{
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(event, args) {
        $scope.userName = args.username;
      });
     //some other code
});
```

Comment: Actually, thinking again, this is probably what you'll have to do because your digest cycle won't run in the other controllers otherwise. So unless there's something to trigger a digest cycle in abcController when something happens in userNameController you won't see a change in userName even *if* you would see it if it looked. My suggestion will get userName propagated through your service OK, but you'd need some other mechanism to trigger the $digest for abcController.